# Loading HTML from a .res file

Tags: html, vb6, resources

Using VS2005/2008 as a resource editor, one of the options in the Add Resource dialog is HTML: it appears to allow me to embed HTML file(s) into a resource (res) file. Does anyone know how to grab the HTML (as a string) from VB6 code? The [LoadResData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244129(VS.60).aspx) appears to be close to what I'm looking for but the problem is there isn't a HTML format defined in the table of formats (in that documentation link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Win32 C headers a resource format constant is defined called RT_HTML, it has the value 23. It should be possible to load the HTML resource type. Additionally you can verify the resource type number by looking at the built exe file with [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/). It lists the resource format types and resource IDs embedded in the file.

Answer (score 0):

here is a good tutorial in c++ http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/index.php?showtopic=15281
you can probably adapt the code(usually function names are the same for win32 routines search on msdn.microsoft.com for documentation) or search the website for a VB example